# c# - How to print the text of some labels?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I have in my program some labels like:

```
Name: Paul
Bought: bike
```

I just want to print this. I was trying to do this with PrintDialog and with PrintDocument but without success. I do not know how to get the text of these labels and print. To be more specific, I don't know how to print anything.

Is the first time I'm trying to do something like this, I would be very grateful if anyone who knows how to print in C# help me.

Comment: If you tried something please post it. This is not a please code this for me site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# printing has almost no difference with just painting. It's very simple:

```
public void PrintThemAll()
{
    var document = new PrintDocument();
    document.PrintPage += document_PrintPage;
    document.Print();
}

void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var graphics = e.Graphics;
    var normalFont = new Font("Calibri", 14); 

    var pageBounds = e.MarginBounds;
    var drawingPoint = new PointF(pageBounds.Left, (pageBounds.Top + normalFont.Height));

    graphics.DrawString("Name: Paul", normalFont, Brushes.Black, drawingPoint);

    drawingPoint.Y += normalFont.Height;

    graphics.DrawString("Bought: bike", normalFont, Brushes.Black, drawingPoint);

    e.HasMorePages = false; // No pages after this page.
}
```

You need to create PrintDocument object, and add handler for PrintPage event. PrintPage handler will be called every time while HasMorePages is set to true(if it's set to false - current page is last). Inside handler you can draw whatever you want to be in printed document.